# Who exactly does SE Inc. consider "Meta"?

Tags: support, meta

In the new blog post [Community working group updates: February 2020](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/02/17/community-working-group-updates-february-2020) we were told:

> We’ve got a broad group of folks looking at the problem of how far out of alignment we’ve become with our meta community.

First of all, I appreciate the efforts about more transparency. It is **good** to hear that SE Inc. is following up on announcements and work is going on in the background.

But what is **still** open for me: a clear definition of whom exactly SE Inc. is talking to.

What I mean is: the above sentence uses singular. **One** Meta that is. Does that refer to:

- The StackOverflow Meta
- This Meta
- "All" Meta communit**ies**

You see, that makes a **huge** difference. And one that matters to people. Lately, it seems that most of your efforts are focussing on that very first option (stackoverflow in isolation).

Thus, kind request: please clarify whom SE Inc. considers to be "Meta".

And in case it isn't clear to "yourself" yet, please clarify internally. And then let us know.

Comment: "We all need to be on the same page about the role that meta plays in decisions, and expectations need to be set and consistently met. **We’re close to being done with a plan to move forward and we’ll be sharing it with you soon.**" Your answers are probably in that plan, which will be shared "soon". Probably not today and not tomorrow though, so what do you intent to accomplish with this question? We know they won't be rushed by you asking it.

Comment: Next sentence: "The folks in this group have worked with us for the longest, and many have a long history of working both with and within our meta _communities_."

Comment: One wonders why meta posts important to the community at large seem to be going to SO meta.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

A bunch of people worked on that blog post, but I'm the one that put everyone's input and work into something that resembled coherency. Had I caught that exact phrase that you cited, I would have written "communities" instead, because we're referring to everyone that considers meta a major influence on how they participate on the main site.

At the same time, here's some observations that matter:

- "Meta" can often refer to *a platform* as well as a group of people with the word taking on a strange duality in conversations. I found this to be somewhat common within internal conversations and the source of some confusion.
- Meta communities are comprised of people that use the *platform* quite differently. If you regularly read meta but don't do much else, and it affects how you interact with the main site, you're a part of that community, just like you would be if you used the main site only occasionally while participating primarily on the meta platform.
- We can refer to "all" broadly, but the communities focused primarily on one site tend to have different personalities, goals and needs. Speaking of them in the singular sense acknowledges that, but should be qualified with "whichever one(s) you identify as being part of." Parenting Meta and MSO are very, very different communities, even though they overlap in membership.

There's more nuance than would have fit there so I'm glad you asked, but as you also alluded, we're still re-thinking how we should be thinking.

Comment: I've been searching how to word a proper appreciation for this answer, I'm short on word but it feels wrong to speak only about criticism. So thanks for this clarification.

Comment: To summarize the answer: the Meta community is every user influenced by the meta platform one way or the other.